# Creating a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I created a data frame in r called "test". When I am trying to add a column it  throws me an error. Below is the code i use to create a column:

```
test$survived[test$sex == "male"] <- 1
```

Error I get:

```
Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "survived", value = numeric(0)) : 
replacement has 0 rows, data has 418
```

I also tried using ifelse but it gives me the same error message. I have just started using R. Would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this with the `iris` dataset like this:

```
iris$newcol[iris$blub == "blub"] <- 1
#Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "newcol", value = numeric(0)) : 
#  replacement has 0 rows, data has 150
```

There is no column `sex` in `test`. (Keep in mind that variable names in R are case-sensitive.)

Comment: Hi Roland, Thank you  for your quick response. I got this and also fixed it. Will be more aware regarding this going forward....:)