# Filling empty dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have used the search box for this and have found [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161921/creating-a-dataframe-in-r), but not identical ones. It seems that this is an easy problem though (I'm an R-newbee).

I am simply trying to create a new data frame and adding values to it. Not surprisingly, R throws an error saying that the rows don't match.

Here's the code

```
d <- data.frame() 

files <- list.files(pattern="*.lst", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
d$fileName <- lapply(files, basename)
d$node <- gsub("([^.]+)\.[^\.lst]+\.lst", "$1", d$fileName, perl=TRUE)
```

And here's the error

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "fileName", value =
>   list("A-bom.WR-P-E-A.lst",  :    replacement has 337 rows, data has 0

How would I go about this problem? I thought about filling `d` with the same amount of rows as there are files, but I don't think that that's the best way?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen See [the docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/basename.html) and [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366186/in-r-loop-through-directory-and-store-filename-in-column#comment-46916669).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create your data frame when it's used the fist time, so you don't "add" rows to a data frame with zero rows. And you may use `sapply` to return a (named) vector instead of a list.

```
files <- list.files(pattern="*.lst", full.names=T, recursive=FALSE)
d <- data.frame(fileName = unname(sapply(files, basename)))
d$node <- gsub("([^.]+)\\.[^\\.lst]+\\.lst", "$1", d$fileName, perl=TRUE)
```

Your regular expression caused an error, however, I'm not that familiar with regex, so you probably have to fix my fixes ;-)

Comment: Ah yes, this works. Thanks! (Apparently `gsub` can't handle capturing groups, so that was the problem. Fixed that now.)